# Phonegap android offline external webpage

Tags: cordova, http-redirect, offlineapps

I'm writing an application using Phonegap and Jquery (for Android so for but plain to add support for other platform) and I would like to know the best way for caching external webpage.

Indeed my application will have somes links to external website (like yahoo or google) and I would like to make those link available for user while they are no connexion.

I have already implemented a simple mechanism to store html file to the filesystem but I would like to have support for CSS file.

My issue is that I do the following:

- download the html page (using phonegap filetranfer object).
- parse the html for css reference
- build url pointing to css file in case they are not linked with an absolut link
- use again phonegap to retrieve all the css files.

This is not working properly in case there is a http redirection in the initial url as the url I generate for the css goes wrong.

Does someone already implemented support for external page and can share its best practices or have some hint to retreive the redirected url in order to solve my issue with my implementation?

Thanks so much

Best Regards

Florent

This is not really working fine because the

Comment: I am also facing a similar kind of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424499/phonegap-offline-caching-website any workarounds?

Comment: Not for the moment, looks like we are a few to need this :)